# Setting negative width in printf()?

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting

What is the point of setting negative width if it doesn't actually move any pixels to the left, for instance:

```
System.out.printf("%-9s", "Name:"); //even though I have -9 it doesn't actually move to the left
```

however having:

```
System.out.printf("%9s", "Name:"); //moves Name to the right 9 pixels
```

So what is the point of the (-) width if it doesn't actually move it to the left?

**Note:** I use intelliJ so maybe its something with my IDE?

Comment: the - isn't a width specifier, it's a justification specifier.

Comment: the number here is **characters**, not *pixels*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the width reserves a minimum number of spaces for your output.  It does not move the beginning left or right.  It simply right-justifies your output at the edge of the width you've designated.

Then, if your output is less then the width you set, it will fill the remaining spaces with whitespace.  If your output however is larger than the width you set, it will move your output in order to fit it all in.

For example...

```
System.out.printf("%9s", "Name:");
```

Will look like:

```
"    Name:"
```

While:

```
System.out.printf("%9s", "His Name:");
```

Will look like:

```
"His Name:"
```

Meanwhile, the `-` is a justification specifier, so:

```
System.out.printf("%-9s", "Name:");
```

Actually looks like:

```
"Name:    "
```

When you have doubts about these sorts of things, try changing your output.  Using something like `System.out.printf("[%-9s]", "Name:")` makes the white space a lot more obvious.